# How can I get selected text on a element click event?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I can get selected text on button click event. But i want get it on a element click event.

Here is my code. Thanks advance

```js
function GetSelectedText(){
    console.log(getSelection().toString());
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum, nam!</p>
<a role="button" id="a" onclick="GetSelectedText()">a element</a>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="GetSelectedText()">Button</button>
```

Comment: What is stopping you from achieving this?

Comment: Result is empty on a element click event

Comment: It looks like the problem isn't "using an element like a button", but rather that clicking on *text* de-selects other selected text.  I don't necessarily have a solution at this time, just trying to clarify the question for everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding an event to your a tag this way.

```js
function GetSelectedText(){
  selectedText = getSelection().toString();
  console.log(selectedText);
}

document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum, nam!</p>
<a role="button" id="a" onclick="GetSelectedText()">a element</a>
<button type="button" id="button" onclick="GetSelectedText()">Button</button>
```